# Ubuntu Installation from SD card always fails

Tags: system-installation, usb, sd-card

I have tried installing versions 14.04, 17.10 and 18.04 on my desktop which has a Windows 8.1 installation already, as a dual boot system. If I burn the installation image to an SD/microSD card and use it with a USB reader (there is no built-in card reader), after the user inputs, the installer just fails saying that there was an error accessing the files, which could be due to bad CD/DVD media. However this error does not occur when I use a standard USB drive. I have tried multiple SD cards and different USB readers on different ports, and I make sure not to touch the media while the installation is happening, to ensure that I don't cause contact errors. I don't understand why this is happening. Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO file?  Did you ever run the "media check" on SD/USB setup?  How big is the SD and what type is it and what is the reader rated for?

Comment: ... and which tool did you use to make the SD card into a boot drive?

Comment: @ubfan1 Sorry, I never checked the ISOs, but since they worked everytime with a USB, I thought it didn't matter. I didn't know there was a check media function. I tried it on 4 different microSD cards, a 16GB class 10, two 8GB class 4 cards, one from Kingston and the other from Sandisk, and an older 4GB class 4, and three different cards readers, one of which was branded Amkette. I have used Unetbootin, Etcher and Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator tool, for each set of images. No matter what combo I use, pendrive always works and SD cards always fail.

Comment: I can make SD boot drives with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), but I think the tools you mention are also good tools (Startup Disk Creator only in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions). And if the media check shows that the drive is good, there is another problem. *Booting via a USB card reader is not as reliable as booting directly via a USB pendrive.* Some cards readers can boot some computers, other card readers may boot some other computers. They usually work, when already booted in order to read/write data on cards, but booting is more finicky.

Comment: @sudodus I can boot and run the live image with persistance without trouble on the SDs, it's just that when I go for installation, the media fails.

Comment: That is strange! It seems that some driver is quitting before finishing a read task before it should, maybe between the operating system and the card reader or between the card reader and the card. Is this a problem also in other computers? Or are you trying to install into the SD card instead of installing into another drive (the internal drive or another external drive)?

Comment: Please tell us which iso files you are using (the whole name of the iso files). What happens if you create a boot drive without persistence (a live-only drive)?

Comment: I am installing from SD/USB flash drive, to a partition on the HDD that is 15GB in size. I haven't tried persistence with disks created other than Unetbootin (it has a persistance checkbox), but even the live images created with Etcher and USDC haven't shown any problems while browsing the Web and saving files to the HDD. I have used the default Ubuntu images, by going to alternate downloads and selecting the torrents for the Desktop version (amd64). I can't see the names right now, I can add a comment later if needed, but I can assure you all three ISOs are torrented from official ubuntu site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79351/discussion-between-sudodus-and-salmonlawyer).